# Proxy extension not installed

Tags: firefox-addon

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file) manual I tried to set the proxy extension.

In `my_prof_dir/extensions` there was my already installed and working (unpacked) extension named my_guid.xpi.

I created a file named `my_guid` and the content was "path_to_my_extension_directory". I deleted `my_guid.xpi` and restarted Firefox. After restart Firefox deleted `my_guid` file
and extension is not installed any more.

Should I do something different?

version: `Firefox 8.0`

thank you

Comment: You shouldn't change the way an existing extension is installed (i.e. directory/xpi -> "pointer file"). Does it help if you start with a profile where your extension is not installed at all, close Firefox, then add the pointer file? If not, you should post the exact path, name, and contents of the pointer, say what your OS is, and if there's any useful output when you set extensions.logging.enabled just before installing your "pointer file" to the extensions/ directory (for details see the "setting up..." page you linked to).

Comment: For those voting to close, "proxy extension" refers not to a specific extension, but to setting a development environment for writing extensions.

Comment: I created a new profile. I created `extensions` directory and added a file `myexample@xralf.com` . I added a string to the file `"/home/xralf/.s/firefox/myexample/"` The directory `myexample` contains `install.rdf` file. I started firefox with new profile `firefox -P dev2 -no-remote`. The only thing that happened is that the pointer file `myexample@xralf.com` was deleted. I'm using `Ubuntu 11.10`.

Comment: I got it. The fault was that the string should only be `/home/xralf/.s/firefox/myexample/`. They had mistake in the documentation. But I'm still disappointed. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077719/fastest-way-to-debug-firefox-addons-during-development) is claimed that restart of Firefox is not needed, this works with opening new window and this not work when opening new tab. Can this be cured?

Comment: @Nickolay Thank you for inspiring me reading the documentation once again. You can write it as answer. If you would know how to cure the above behaviour it would be yet greater.

Comment: you mean the quotes? You know you can edit developer.mozilla.org; it's a wiki. As a matter of fact the quotes and the "extension proxy" name was added by one of the editors later.

Comment: OK I can register there. Maybe some note about the quotes would be sufficient for people like me who make stupid mistakes.

Comment: btw, I answered your other question in a comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077719/fastest-way-to-debug-firefox-addons-during-development). And let me know if you don't get to update developer.m.o, I'll do it for you, since the quotes there indeed make the getting started process even more confusing than it already is.

Comment: Yes, please update it. I will probably register to that developers network, but later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change the way an existing extension is installed (i.e. directory/xpi -> "pointer file"). Does it help if you start with a profile where your extension is not installed at all, close Firefox, then add the pointer file?

If not, you should check:

- the exact path, name, and contents of the pointer file. (Pay attention to the tips @ [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file).)
- check that the path format you're using matches your OS native paths
- check the output in the Error Console after setting `extensions.logging.enabled` preference in about:config, then quitting Firefox and installing your "pointer file" to the `extensions/` directory (for details see [Setting up extension development environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment)).
- Does the extension get installed if you copy all content (when Firefox is closed)

  - from the folder pointed to by the "proxy/pointer" file
  - to the folder named exactly as the pointer file (you'll need to delete the pointer file first).