# firefox restartless bootstrap extension script not reloading

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I am unable to get a source code modification reflected in the firefox extension without restarting firefox.
I believe this should be possible when using the bootstrap approach.

Here is the source code:
**bootstrap.js**

```
var GOOGBAR_MODULES = [ "resource://googbar/loader.js"];

function startup(params, reason)
{

    var res = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource").QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandler);
    var modulesURI = Services.io.newURI(__SCRIPT_URI_SPEC__ + "/../content/", null, null);
    res.setSubstitution("googbar", modulesURI);
    Cu.import("resource://googbar/loader.js");
} 


function shutdown(params, reason)
{ 
    // Unload all modules added with Cu.import
    GOOGBAR_MODULES.forEach(Cu.unload, Cu);

    // Clear our resource registration
    var res = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource").QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandler);
    res.setSubstitution("googbar", null);

}
```

**loader.js**

```
console.log("googbar loader loaded");
```

when i change the message in the loader, it doesnt get reflected in firefox (version 30). I have a file "goog@myself.com" in the profile extensions folder which contains the path to my development folder.
The changes I made to loader.js doesnt reflect when I enable/disable or remove/undo from the about:extensions page, unless i restart firefox.
Any pointers to why the code is not loading dynamically would be helpful.

I am not interested in using the SDK for development. I have also set various flags as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment

**EDIT 1:**

Here is a link to above code packaged as an xpi(1.35KB) i am using to test the scenario. https://www.dropbox.com/s/0io8b081ybu632q/test.xpi

**EDIT 2:**

My goal is to speed up the development process without having to restart the browser for every code change. Here is a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077719/fastest-way-to-debug-firefox-addons-during-development), but seems to be an outdated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AddonManager` or more specifically the `XPIProvider` calls [`flushStartupCache`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e1a037c085d1/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/internal/XPIProvider.jsm#l1172) but only when the add-on is uninstalled (incl. during up- and downgrades). However, the cache is not cleared when disabling or enabling an add-on in-session.

- Either put an equivalent method in your `bootstrap.js` that you call when `shutdown` (you should do this in release versions).
- Or just continue restating that damn browser. Personally I find it faster to just restart with the ["Restartless Restart"](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/restartless-restart/) add-on keyboard shortcut and roaming around in about:addons.

PS: I can not be absolutely sure this is the only issue at play, since I cannot test your stuff, since you didn't provide a *full*, reproducible example.

*Edit* Yes, indeed, adding the following to shutdown is sufficient and there are no other blocking issues:

```
if (reason == ADDON_DISABLE) {
  Services.obs.notifyObservers(null, "startupcache-invalidate", null);
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question to provide a link to the xpi i am using.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Just curious to know what other blocking issues can possibly arise.